# WP Query custom meta ordering

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to sort my custom post type by custom meta value (post_views).

```
<?php

$popular = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'question',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'posts_per_archive_page' => 5,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'meta_key' => PREFIX . 'post_views',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    )
);

?>
```

My ten posts are not ordered by post_views.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem was with me i have done it with custom query and its working for.

Hope this on will help you.

```
<?php
        $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'year'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'portfolio'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value DESC";
    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
        ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks, your answer is usefull but finally I found the issue. I'm using a custom post type order plugin and it order auto by menu_order. I just needed to disable that option. thanks!